# Single word for "level of revealed knowledge"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can be used to describe the amount of knowledge that has been revealed to a person or population.

For example, if I was studying a culture that didn't have access to computers, and I wanted to describe the "level of knowledge" that the population had been exposed to (as opposed to the level of knowledge that they actually had), is there an academic term for describing this concept?

Another example: if I wanted to talk about, how the level of knowledge that a culture had been exposed to was slowly changing traditions around child brides, what word could/should I use to describe the "measure of revelation?"

I considered the word **revelation**:

(*dictionary.com*)

> **noun**
>
> **1.**
>   *the act of revealing or disclosing; disclosure.*
>
> **2.**
>   *something revealed or disclosed, especially a striking disclosure, as of something not before realized.*

However, that particular word has obvious religious connotations, and it is more often used to describe a surprising discovery in my experience.

Honestly, the best phrase I have so far is, ***"measure of revelation."***

Comment: "Honestly, the best phrase I have so far is "measure of revelation."  Please provide a complete sentence.

Comment: I don't think one can be 'exposed' to a 'level' of knowledge. One can be granted access to a _body_ of knowledge and that body of knowledge may be large or small.

Comment: 'Degree of education' I would suggest, but it depends on what your example sentence is going to be.

Comment: Your own term works: [exposure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exposure) (definition 1.2).

Comment: maybe  a 'gauge'

Comment: I assume by "knowledge" you don't mean *information / data*, but something more like *understanding / wisdom*. But there's a world of difference between matters [*of **revealed** truth*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22of+revealed+truth%22) (religion) and [*of **verifiable** truth*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22of+verifiable+truth%22) (the scientific method). And what about ***indoctrination*** (what 1984's Big Brother tells you is true)?

Comment: "familiarity" is another descriptive words for partial knowledge of one culture with another ... although if you are set on a noun form to single out inidivual topics the words are less useful as they start taking on other nuances in those forms. "Level of familiarity"

Comment: @NigelJ  "How familiar are you with the Japanese concept of Bushido" or "How familiar are you with the history of the Evangelical movement in the US" .... or "How familiar are you with the iPhone user interface?" are normal everyday questions about "degree of knowledge" .. many many things are known in degree ... not a series of individual data points that can be added together.

Answer (score 1):

If I read the question correctly, you would like a word which you could in turn use a quanitfier with (or a magnifier) to rate a degree of 'understanding' or "knowledge about"

I would suggest the word Familiar  - or as a noun Familiarity

> **[Familiar](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/familiar)**
>
> 1Well known from long or close association.
>
> *‘their faces will be familiar to many of you’*
>
> *‘a familiar voice’*
>
> 1.1 Often encountered or experienced; common.
>   ‘the situation was all too familiar’
>
> 1.2familiar with Having a good knowledge of.
>
> ‘ensure that you are familiar with the heating controls’

The term I think applies best with degrees of exposure below expertise (in which case, you would then choose something beyond "extremely familiar" .. you'd use expert.

While the dictionary definition above does not entirely illucidate that flavor of the word, I think that it is often chosen because of it's room for degrees of 'room for failure'.

The term, from perhaps it's heavy use with knowledge of 'flavor" or 'personality' works well with complex subjects in which a person can have partial understanding of individual aspects within the larger topic too .... cultural knowledge is far from Boolean  - understanding a definition and having a cultural attitude explained so you can repeat it would still fall short of understanding it in the same way that one that shares that tradition might feel.

Answer (score -2):

I cannot think of a single word for this, but perhaps consider two words such as "revelation quotient".  You could even call it the "RQ".